# Help with the basic idea of free choices for Sartre

Tags: existentialism, sartre, freedom

> what is required of an authentic choice is that it involve a proper
> coordination of transcendence and facticity, and thus that it avoid
> the pitfalls of an uncoordinated expression of the desire for being.
> This amounts to not-grasping oneself as freedom and facticity. Such a
> lack of proper coordination between transcendence and facticity
> constitutes bad faith, either at an individual or an inter-personal
> level. Such a notion of authenticity is therefore quite different from
> what is often popularly misrepresented as a typically existentialist
> attitude, namely an absolute prioritisation of individual spontaneity.
> On the contrary, a recognition of how our freedom interacts with our
> facticity exhibits the responsibility which we have to make proper
> choices

https://iep.utm.edu/sartre-ex/

1. Does freedom and facticity mean that I am subject to all that I am becasue I am free?
2. In what sense would that make for a "proper choice": how is it different to spontaneity considered as properly responding to things as they are?

Comment: If you're *free* why you're *subject* to *all* that you are? Spontaneity shouldn't be considered as authentic responding as it's about your 'being subject to' facticity as hinted by Shurangama Sutra long ago: *Even empty space is an illusory creation; how much the more so are causes and conditions and spontaneity...if you perceive the arising of falseness, you can speak of the causes and conditions of that falseness. But if the falseness has no source...causes and conditions...have no source. How much the more is this the case for those who fail to understand this and advocate spontaneity...*

Comment: Right. I was thinking that Sartre obfuscates what the Buddha makes clear. Nonduality is a more recent way of getting to it.

Answer (score 1):

In the [Sartre link](https://iep.utm.edu/sartre-ex/) this is mentioned:

> The main features of this ontology are the groundlessness and radical
> freedom which characterize the human condition.

Sartre picked up a lot from Heidegger and assuming he kept to Heidegger's understanding of freedom then he is talking about the freedom that allows/constitutes human transcendence.  That is, transcendence to consciousness, or, from 'not being' to 'being a being'.  Not just in the first instance of coming into being but in the fullest sense, as a self.

This is described in Heidegger's 1929 treatise [*On the Essence of Ground*](https://web.archive.org/web/20151028052521/http://users.clas.ufl.edu/burt/spliceoflife/Heideggerground.pdf) (Pathmarks, p. 126):-

> All forms of comportment are rooted in transcendence. The "will" in
> question, however, must first "form" the "for­ the-sake-of" itself as
> and in a surpassing. Yet whatever, in accordance with its essence,
> casts something like the "for the sake of" projectively before it,
> rather than simply producing it as an occasional and additional
> accomplish­ment, is that which we call *freedom*. Surpassing in the
> direction of world is freedom itself. Accordingly, transcendence does
> not merely come upon the "for the sake of" as anything like a value or
> end that would be present at hand in itself; rather, freedom holds the
> "for the sake of" *toward* itself, *and does so as freedom*.  In this
> transcending that holds the "for the sake of" toward itself there
> occurs the Dasein in human beings, such that in the essence of their
> existence they can be obligated to themselves, i.e., be free selves.

Comment: Is there a simplified version, or Camus' Notes or something? These guys always sound completely schizophrenic to me.

Comment: @ScottRowe There are a few arcane terms in that particular treatise : [for-the-sake-of-which](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/cambridge-heidegger-lexicon/forthesakeofwhich-umwillen-worumwillen/1123E22E7D65C7E95D3107BE5AFDF528) & *ab-grund*. Nicely summarised in J. Backman's [*The Absent Foundation*](https://helda.helsinki.fi/bitstream/handle/10138/160985/Backman_Absent_Foundation_submitted_manuscript.pdf) though, e.g. p. 12: "freedom is not the arbitrary absence of grounds. On the contrary, freedom as transcendence *is* the original relationship to Being as the back-ground of beings."